# Angular Shorthand CSS broken during optimization

Tags: angular

I have a style set to the following on a class in my application using shorthand like this.

```
my-thing: {
 font: var(...) var(...) var(...);
}
```

This works in development but when I enable `optimization` and `buildOptimizer`

It generates this:

```
 font: var(...), var(...), var(...);
```

Notice the commas. This is not valid CSS and the end result is that the style doesn't apply.

I am using the Angular CLI and SCSS. Is there something I am missing with either the declaration of shorthand css variables, or some property I need to try to configure in the minification process of my Angular.json to prevent this occurring?